# Converting 16 bit binary number to decimal using only if-else statements

Tags: python, if-statement, numbers, decimal

I need to write a program that asks the user to enter a 16-bit binary number and then converts it to decimal. I am only allowed to use the if-else statement (no for/while etc.. and no functions).

My problem is not the conversion itself.

My problem is representing the user's number as a 16-bit number once he entered a number with less then 16 digits. For example, if the user entered "1111" I need to convert it to "0000 0000 0000 1111".

I tried :

```
    A=int(input("Please enter a 16-bit decimal number:"))
    B=0000000000000000
    C=A or B
    print (C)
```

which gave me the original number in A (I don't realy understand why).

I also tried to look at the user's input as a string but, as I understand it, Python starts to number the chars from left to right so in case of A=1111 I have only A[0]-A[3]
so I was kind of stuck with it.

I know there are functions that I can use but, the assignment is to use only the subjects we learned in class which is basically only the if-else statement (and assignment statements).

Thank you.
Yul

Comment: `C=A or B`  or is logical `or`  not bitwise, and  Logical `and`, `or` operators in Python returns operand's value instead of Boolean `True`, `False`.

Comment: Were you looking for `|` and `&` perhaps? Not that they are needed, as you *already* use `int()`, all you need to do is add `, 2)`.. :-P

Comment: Yes,I was looking for | .

Comment: Why should I add ,2) ? What does it do?

Answer (score 3):

Note that both `int()` and `input()` are functions.

Also note that `int()` does exactly what you say you should do *without* functions, i.e. it converts a string to a number.

This is very confusing.

Assuming you do have a string `s` with exactly 16 binary digits in it, you can convert it to an integer like so:

```
num = 0
if s[0] == '1':
  num += 1
if s[1] == '1':
  num += 2
if s[2] == '1':
  num += 4
```

and so on up to `s[15]` which would add `32768` to `num`.

You can "squeeze out" the `if`s by doing it like this:

```
num = 0
num += (s[0] == '1') * 1
num += (s[1] == '1') * 2
num += (s[2] == '1') * 4
...
num += (s[15] == '1') * 32768
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant no functions that actually convert binary to decimal.

Comment: Nice way to do it with just if's